# JSP custom tags: missing DTD/XML Schema

Tags: java, jsp-tags

I've written my JSP custom tag with the following TLD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  version="2.1">
  <tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion> 
  <jspversion>2.1</jspversion>
  ...
```

Now Eclipse Helios complains that "No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document."

I know how to disable the warning, I was instead wondering how to solve the problem by providing DTD or schema information.

By the way in the above piece of XML I have:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
```

but it doesn't seem to help.

**UPDATE** on Peter's suggestion I went to check in my Window > Preferences > XML > XML Catalog and I found the following that may fit:

```
Entry element:  Public
Location:   dtdsAndSchemas/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd in jar file 
usr/local/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.standard.schemas_1.1.0.v201003031644.jar
URI:       jar:file:/usr/local/eclipse/plugins/org
  .eclipse.jst.standard.schemas_1.1.0.v201003031644.jar!/dtdsAndSchemas
  /web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd
Key type:   Public ID
Key:    -//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN
```

So I tried to add the following to my tld:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.2//EN" 
"http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd">
```

Now I've the following errors:

Multiple annotations found at this line:

- Attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" must be declared for element type "taglib".
- Attribute "version" must be declared for element type "taglib".
- Attribute "xmlns" with value "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" must have a value of "http://java.sun.com/JSP/ TagLibraryDescriptor".
- schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd', because

  1) could not find the document; 
  2) the document could not be read; 
  3) the root element of the document is not .
- The content of element type "taglib" must match "(tlib-version,jsp-version,short-name,uri?,display-name?,small-icon?,large-icon?,description?,validator?,listener*,tag+)".
- Attribute "xmlns:xsi" must be declared for element type "taglib".

Comment: My first question would be, are you using Eclipse for Java EE Developers?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the package for Java EE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Eclipse doesn't automatically pick up the XSD from the library, you can always add it manually:
Window > Preferences > XML > XML Catalog

In my case it was already present in the plugin section. It probably came with one of the Eclipse Java EE plugins.

Comment: Thanks, updated the questions, seems I've more problems now :-)

Comment: In the end I am accepting your answer, because it answered my original question, even if I wasn't able to use your suggestion, because it introduced more problems.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer your follow up problem. It got lost somewhere. I would suggest a full reinstall of Eclipse. It looks like there's something completely messed up with either the XML validator or the J2EE XSD files

Comment: I will try some days later and let you know since now I've some work pressure. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Peter! After over a month, I've looked again at this problem and solved it, see my answer.

Answer (score 14):

I didn't bother looking at this problem for over a month, because anyway everything was working in Tomcat. Recently I tried GlassFish and JBoss. While GlassFish 3.1.1 didn't complain, JBoss 7.0 refused to run the application, because of tld problems. In the meantime I've also updated Eclipse Helios to Indigo.

I figured out that I was using DTD and Schema at the same time, which can't be good. I ditched the DTD and kept only the Schema. I had to rename a few tags, such as tlibversion to tlib-version, shortname to short-name, bodycontent to body-content, tagclass to tag-class, remove the info tag, which I substituted with XML comments. I guess it's probably a newer version of the specs, because in the example I followed they were named without hyphens.

After that everything worked: Eclipse didn't give any warning any more, JBoss ran the application perfectly. For reference here is the working tld:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        version="2.1">
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version> 
    <short-name>StivloTags</short-name>
    <uri>http://www.stefanolocati.it/</uri>

    <!-- Example from http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2001081301&amp;page=1 -->
    <tag> 
        <name>firstTag</name> 
        <tag-class>obliquid.tag.FirstTag</tag-class>
        <body-content>empty</body-content> 
        <attribute>
            <name>name</name>
            <required>false</required>
        </attribute>
    </tag> 

    <!-- Truncate text after maxLength or 80 chars, adding "&amp;hellip;" if the the text was longer -->
    <tag>
        <name>ellipsis</name>
        <tag-class>obliquid.tag.Ellipsis</tag-class>
        <body-content>scriptless</body-content>
        <attribute>
             <name>maxLength</name>
             <required>false</required>
        </attribute>
    </tag>

</taglib>
```

Comment: version 2.0 found on Oracle docs does not seem to work. 2.1 is good !

Answer (score 1):

its 
 [java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd](http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd)
not 
http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_2.dtd

go to the second link you will see. 
faced the same problem . the file itself said that the location is changed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).